# Merging pages from a single PDF

Tags: pdf

I have been sent a 3-fold (4 facet, double-sided so 8 page per sheet) leaflet as a PDF. I'd like to print it but none of the Okular print options offer sticking 4 sides *next* to each other. It's always a grid.

The PDF is currently presented as one long and thin portrait page per page. I would like to merge these so that the pages are combined in sets of 4 side-by side, leaving a landscape document that I can easily send to the printer.

Just to clarify, there are a lot of questions about merging multiple documents into one. I have no interest in that. I have one document whose pages I wish to merge down.